# using history.js so that i can deep link on a website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pushstate, history.js

I am trying to to deep link in my site. what i mean by this is that i can go to a url like

http://test.madeup.com/?campaign=funkyNew

If go to this it will change the page display and bring the funkynew campaign to the top.

I have been going through the example of history.js and have a couple of questions.

so the example code is something like this

```
// Establish Variables

var History = window.History, // Note: We are using a capital H instead of a lower h
State = History.getState(),
$log = $('#log');

// Log Initial State
History.log('initial:', State.data, State.title, State.url);

// Bind to State Change
History.Adapter.bind(window,'statechange',function(){ // Note: We are using statechange instead of popstate

       // Log the State
       var State = History.getState(); // Note: We are using History.getState() instead of event.state
       History.log('statechange:', State.data, State.title, State.url);

       alert("stateChanged - run function");
});

// Prepare Buttons
var
    buttons = document.getElementById('buttons'),
    scripts = [
        'History.pushState({state:1,rand:12345}, "Test", "?campaign=funkyNew"); '
    ],
    buttonsHTML = '';

// Add Buttons
for ( var i=0,n=scripts.length; i<n; ++i ) {
    var _script = scripts[i];
    buttonsHTML +=
        '<li><button onclick=\'javascript:'+_script+'\'>'+_script+'</button></li>';
}
buttons.innerHTML = buttonsHTML;
```

and this works by clicking on the button changing the url and then the variables are shown. This works ok.

What I need to do is go direct to the url with the funkynew and get the variables and get it to run a function.

Obviously, it wont work now because history is only created when the buttons are pushed - so how could I go about having these there at the beginning so that if I go direct to the funkyCampaign ie from another url I see the variables

does this make sense?

Thanks for any help

Dan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if you figured out a way to deep linking.

The below works for me. It basically get the params from url and forms a state and replaces the current(initial) state with it.

```
// Bind to State Change
History.Adapter.bind(window,'statechange',function(){ 
   // Log the State
   var State = History.getState(); 
   History.log('statechange:', State.data, State.title, State.url);

   alert("stateChanged - run function");
});

var utils = utils || {};
utils.getParameterByName: function (name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
    results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
};

//On page load route to appropriate screen
if(urlParamSection = utils.getParameterByName('section')){
    History.replaceState({
            section: urlParamSection
        }, // This is state's data
        'MySite - ' + urlParamSection.toUpperCase(), //Title to the state
        window.location.protocol+"//"+window.location.host + "?section=" + urlParamSection // this is actually the page load url
    );
}
```

Comment: For other ways of getting the query string values, refer to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript